# In Visual Studio 10 IronPython console disappears before I can read the error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, error-handling, console-application, ironpython

In Visual Studio 10 IronPython console disappears before I can read the error.
When I surround this code by try/except-block I do not get the text of error at all.
How must I act in this case?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set subsystem::console in the project properties and using the 'Ctrl+F5' to execute a script.